# Android: Adjusting the position of actionbar overflow menu dropdown

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-studio

I have an issue with my action bar overflow menu dropdown. It is displayed on top of the action bar itself. I want it to be displayed below the action bar and overflow button. I am using android studio for development.

This is my menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.xxx.messageapp.MessageActivity" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_overflow"
        android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always"  android:title="@string/action_messages">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/action_messages" android:title="@string/action_messages"
                android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always" android:icon="@drawable/icon_messages" />
            <item android:id="@+id/action_maps" android:title="@string/action_maps"
                android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always" android:icon="@drawable/icon_bus" />
            <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
                android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always" android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings" />
            <item android:id="@+id/action_logout" android:title="@string/action_logout"
                android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always" android:icon="@drawable/icon_logout"  />
        </menu>
        </item>

</menu>
```

This is my class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_message, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a defect on the support library, a bug has already been filed:
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1776

Regards,
Juan