# Android: Overflow Menu's Dropdown Position

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow, toolbar

I am trying to style the Android toolbar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) so when the overflow menu icon is clicked, the overflow menu appears [below the toolbar](http://developer.android.com/design/media/action_bar_pattern_share_pack.png), rather than [the Material Design style](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B_udO5B8pzrzdmJrQUk3aXd0RTg/components_menus_usage2.png). The Material Design style is not an intuitive choice for my app, but it is the default choice when I inflate my menu (onCreateOptionsMenu).

Similar posts can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844056/android-adjusting-the-position-of-actionbar-overflow-menu-dropdown) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638732/android-overflow-menu-positioned-above-actionbar-toolbar), but no solution seems to exist to get the overflow menu to open below the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834089/anchor-popup-menu-over-overflow-button/28955735#28955735). You can use the same ListPopupWindow, but you would adjust your vertical offset until it was below the toolbar.